# How to merge two columns of a `Dataframe` in Spark into one 2-Tuple?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark `DataFrame` `df` with five columns. I want to add another column with its values being the tuple of the first and second columns. When using with withColumn() method, I get the mismatch error, because the input is not Column type, but instead (Column,Column). **I wonder if there is a solution beside running for loop over the rows in this case?**

```
var dfCol=(col1:Column,col2:Column)=>(col1,col2)
val vv = df.withColumn( "NewColumn", dfCol( df(df.schema.fieldNames(1)) , df(df.schema.fieldNames(2)) ) )
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a User-defined function `udf` to achieve what you want.

### UDF definition

```
object TupleUDFs {
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf      
  // type tag is required, as we have a generic udf
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, typeTag}

  def toTuple2[S: TypeTag, T: TypeTag] = 
    udf[(S, T), S, T]((x: S, y: T) => (x, y))
}
```

### Usage

```
df.withColumn(
  "tuple_col", TupleUDFs.toTuple2[Int, Int].apply(df("a"), df("b"))
)
```

assuming "a" and "b" are the columns of type `Int` you want to put in a tuple.

Comment: @TNM: Your edit got rejected unfortunately, as edit comments did not state clearly about wrong import, I used. It is corrected now.

Answer (score 31):

You can use [`struct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#struct-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-) function which creates a tuple of provided columns:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct

val df = Seq((1,2), (3,4), (5,3)).toDF("a", "b")
df.withColumn("NewColumn", struct(df("a"), df("b")).show(false)

+---+---+---------+
|a  |b  |NewColumn|
+---+---+---------+
|1  |2  |[1,2]    |
|3  |4  |[3,4]    |
|5  |3  |[5,3]    |
+---+---+---------+
```

Comment: What if I want to delete the existing `a` and `b` columns? How to do that please?

Comment: @Soumendra `df.drop('a')`.

Comment: This is the better way of doing it. Verified.

Answer (score 6):

You can merge multiple dataframe columns into one using array.

```
// $"*" will capture all existing columns
df.select($"*", array($"col1", $"col2").as("newCol"))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to merge two dataframe columns into one column.
Just:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array
df.withColumn("NewColumn", array("columnA", "columnB"))
```