# Create a dataframe in pyspark that contains a single column of tuples

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an RDD that contains the following [('column 1',value), ('column 2',value), ('column 3',value), ... , ('column 100',value)].
I want to create a dataframe that contains a single column with tuples.

The closest I have gotten is:

```
schema = StructType((StructField("char", StringType(), False), (StructField("count", IntegerType(), False))))
    my_udf = udf(lambda w, c: (w,c), schema)
```

and then

```
df.select(my_udf('char', 'int').alias('char_int'))
```

but this produces a dataframe with a column of lists, not tuples.

Comment: There is no such thing as column of tuples. Struct is the only representation for product types.

Comment: I understand that but that does not help me with my question. Starting with a dataframe that contains two columns, how do I end up with a dataframe that contains a single column which is a tuple of the previous two?

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799595/how-to-merge-two-columns-of-a-dataframe-in-spark-into-one-2-tuple) question that seems sort of similar. Maybe the answers posted there are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`struct` is a s correct way to represent product types, like `tuple`, in Spark SQL and this is exactly what you get using your code:

```py
df = (sc.parallelize([("a", 1)]).toDF(["char", "int"])
    .select(my_udf("char", "int").alias("pair")))
df.printSchema()

## root
##  |-- pair: struct (nullable = true)
##  |    |-- char: string (nullable = false)
##  |    |-- count: integer (nullable = false)
```

There is no other way to represent a tuple unless you want to create an UDT (no longer supported in 2.0.0) or store pickled objects as `BinaryType`.

Moreover `struct` fields are locally represented as `tuple`:

```py
isinstance(df.first().pair, tuple)
## True
```

I guess you may be confused by square brackets when you call `show`:

```py
df.show()

## +-----+
## | pair|
## +-----+
## |[a,1]|
## +-----+
```

which are simply a representation of choice render by JVM counterpart and don't indicate Python types.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Indeed the representation confused me.